# How to prevent saving of remote desktop credentials (IP, username password)?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-connection

I want to disable saving of remote desktop credentials like computer, username and password, disable from saving in history like recent etc.

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: This is the lazy response. In addition to setting the group policy in the answer. You can also use GPO to change, or manually change, permissions to the locations mentioned in this article: https://woshub.com/how-to-clear-rdp-connections-history/ simply deny ‘authenticated users’ from modifying these registry keys and file. Now the RDP client will be unable to save history.

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple via Group Policy, either local or per Domain.

For local:

1. run `gpedit.msc`
2. find `User Configuration`
3. find `Administrative Templates`
4. find `Windows Components`
5. find `Remote Desktop Services`
6. find `Remote Desktop Connection Client`
7. find the Setting `Do not allow passwords to be saved`
8. change appropriately

Comment: i want to remove ip ?

Comment: what do you mean?
You will have to change the setting from "not configured" to "active"

Comment: 0


I want to Disable Saving of Remote Desktop Credentials like computer, username and passsword, disable from saving in history like recent etc.